# Markup enumeration bug: Preview starts at 1, final output starts correctly at 0

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editor

I was just [editing this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25918175/2589202), when I noticed that the enumeration markup has what appears to be a bug.

Using this markup in the editor:

```
0. line 1 
0. line 2
```

The final output looks like this:

1. line 1
2. line 2

(Notice that the numbering starts with 0 when viewing the final output)

However, the preview while editing shows

```
1. line 1
2. line 2
```

In the post I was trying to edit, as well as this post, the final output starts at 0, while the editor preview starts at 1.

This has changed from previous functionality as it used to be 1 based.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to [meta.se] as it is generic to the entire network...

Comment: @Werner, you may be right, I dont think cross-posting is a good idea however, perhaps it should be migrated by a mod.

Comment: I was confused by what you meant at first, so I edited your post to make it more explicit about what was wrong. Hopefully I didn't mess up any details.

Comment: There may be minor discrepancies between the preview and the final version of the post.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi ok, not sure why, but even if you are correct, this used to work the same.  Its a change in the behavior.

Comment: FYI: This behavior seems to be consistent with the [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) [spec](http://jgm.github.io/stmd/spec.html), but not the [CommonMark reference implementation](http://jgm.github.io/stmd/js/).

Comment: @Ajedi32 that is a great find.  [FTA](http://jgm.github.io/stmd/spec.html#ordered-list): `The start number of an ordered list is determined by the list number of its initial list item. The numbers of subsequent list items are disregarded.`  And sure enough, if I use `1. line1` it works.  It would be nice to see some consistency however.

Comment: For anyone wanting to see this in action, clicking 'edit' on this post demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have reproduced the issue and am taking a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. I have fixed a JavaScript bug in our Markdown converter code that would treat ordered lists that start with `0` as if they started with `1` for preview purposes. This will be live in the next build (newer than meta: `rev 2014.9.19.2585`, q&a: `rev 2014.9.19.1875`).

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

It turns out that I lied. After speaking with my colleagues, we have concluded that lists which begin with `0` are an invalid case. I will be pushing out a fix that instead shows both the preview and post list as starting at `1` instead of `0`. In other words, I'm going to do the opposite fix (make the post match the preview instead of the preview match the post).

Comment: Any chance to share some of the reasons? Starting at 0 might be important for some quotes...

Comment: I definitely agree with you. However my peers felt strongly about it and the Markdown spec (and CommonMark spec) don't actually indicate what numbers are valid for lists. I'd say make it a meta post and see if it gets traction?

Comment: @Haney I inadvertently made that Meta post (and would like this to change): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284387/should-the-system-override-my-numbering?noredirect=1#comment146969_284387

Comment: Me, too. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49118161/1566221), I really wanted the first item to be numbered 0, because it is really a note rather than one of the two proposed solutions. (I accept that not everyone will approve of this style, but it's my answer :) ) The workaround suggested in Cory's answer to @BradleyDotNET's question is not satisfactory because both list items include code blocks, massively increasing the amount of HTML which I would have needed to include.