# Mismatch between preview and what is actually posted

Tags: bug, markdown, editor

On the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25106423/456434

I see that the numbered list resets to one on the last point, but when I try to edit, it shows `4.` correctly.

Also, when I remove the `<pre><code>` tags and use the 4 spaces indentation for code, it doesn't work.. something wrong with this answer.

Comment: I think the list-numbering thing is a bug, but as for `<pre><code>` versus indentation, if you want a code block within the list, you need to indent 8 spaces: 4 to say it’s part of the list item, and 4 to say that it’s code.

Comment: Fixed it.... you only needed to put 1 space in front of the `<pre><code>` under item 3 to get it to work (although removing the `<pre><code>` and adding 8 spaces as suggested should have worked too), but the fact that the preview didn't reflect what was actually posted is a legit bug

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271640/markup-enumeration-bug-preview-starts-at-1-final-output-starts-correctly-at-0

Answer (score -2):

I've corrected the answer for you:

1. Don't put a space before the numbers in the list
2. Use eight spaces to indent code within a list
3. Use four spaces to continue text (e.g., a new paragraph) within a list

I also added blank lines to vertically separate the list, but you could remove them if you didn't want them.

FWIW as the answer may still be edited, here's the markdown:

```
All credit goes to jrtuton for this. Is there some way to attribute the answer to him?

Here are the changes made:

1. Removed the Goal class from the compile list for the test target.

2. Added proper access modifiers to the Goal class:

        public class Goal: NSManagedObject {

            @NSManaged public var displayDesc: String
            @NSManaged public var motivation: String
            @NSManaged public var cratedDate: NSDate
            @NSManaged public var goalType: NSNumber

3. Added a public init method:

        public init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:   NSManagedObjectContext) {
            super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:   insertIntoManagedObjectContext)
        }

4. Imported the LifeList module in my test class:

        import LifeList
```

Comment: Although this does fix the issue with the specific answer, I don't really think this addresses the core problem of the preview reflecting the list numbering differently than what is posted.  That is a legit bug.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I don't see that behavior if I view [the OP's original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25106423/1), and then go into [the editor on the OP's original](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25106423/edit/ecbdbe5c-2886-447a-9e6c-77a643880725). I see "4" at the end in both cases. But I think "use correct markup" is a valid response to "something isn't working as I expect it to."

Comment: It existed, I saw it.... [see my comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275922/mismatch-between-preview-and-what-is-action-posted/275960?noredirect=1#comment113167_275922)

Comment: @psubsee2003: I'm not saying you didn't, I'm just adding information: I don't. I've even copied the OP's markdown exactly and pasted it into a new answer (in case the editor varies a bit between clicking edit on a revision vs. a real answer), and the 4 is still a 4 in the preview. So I put a bunch of lorem ipsum at the top (to avoid the auto-dupe check) and posted it, and it was a 4 when posted. Naturally I then deleted it. But again: Answering "use correct markup, here's how" is a valid response to "it doesn't work as I expect."

Comment: That's the problem though..... `it doesn't work as I expect` is not the issue so "use correct markup, here's how" is not a correct response.  The OP here expected it to work as displayed in the preview which is what you are seeing when you look at the revisions.  But when it was actually posted, the result did not match the preview.  Yes, you are correct in that using the correct syntax would have avoided this bug, but it still doesn't address the actual bug.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Whatever. At the end of the day, the goal is to have the preview and post look the same, and using correct markup makes that happen. Not quite working when faced with lots of...inventive...markup doesn't necessarily mean something's a bug, it could be outside of supported parameters. Also, reporting a bug requires a replicable test case; again, you may have seen the issue, but I've tried hard and couldn't.