# How do I override the numbering in lists?

Tags: support, markdown

Today, I noticed a user post an answer to a question. The answer started with

> According to the standard:
>
> 10 [SOME_TEXT]
>
> 14 [SOME_TEXT]

I wanted to edit an make it a list. So I tried editing it into

> According to the standard:
>
> 10. [SOME_TEXT]
>
> 14. [SOME_TEXT]

but the edited text appears like this:

> According to the standard:
>
> 10. [SOME_TEXT]
> 11. [SOME_TEXT]

- Why does StackOverflow override my numbering?
- Is it possible to override the numbering?

Comment: The numbering is overridden by the markdown implementation. This post on MSE might be helpful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137077/cant-start-a-numbered-list-on-a-number-other-than-1

Comment: It would be great if the [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value) attribute of `li` were supported.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately the default markup doesn't support the `value` attribute on the `li` item. I'm not sure why it is not supported but based on [the supported HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites), I tested whether the `ol` element supports the `start` attribute. It does because it has been explicitly [implemented by balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239121/158100):

10. [SOME_TEXT]

14. [SOME_TEXT]
15. [SOME_TEXT next ]

Here is the markup of the above result:

```
<ol start="10">
  <li> [SOME_TEXT] </li>
</ol>
<ol start="14">
  <li> [SOME_TEXT] </li>
  <li> [SOME_TEXT next ] </li>
</ol>
```

It is not exactly what you wanted to achieve, but closer than this it won't get.

Comment: So, this means that I'll have to do this manually?

Comment: @CoolGuy , Yes.

Comment: There are some caveats to this that were mentioned in [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284392/74757) to [Can't start a numbered list on a number other than 1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284387/74757), such as what types of formatting can be achieved within the list items when you use explicit HTML.

Answer (score 14):

It is not necessary to use HTML to achieve this. You can simply split your list into multiple lists and still use markdown syntax by inserting an empty HTML comment.

Content:

```
10. [SOME_TEXT]

<!---->

14. [SOME_TEXT]
15. [SOME_TEXT]
```

Result:

10. [SOME_TEXT]

14. [SOME_TEXT]
15. [SOME_TEXT]

Comment: I see this is already what you did in your question. My bad.

Comment: There is a bigger gap between `10.` and `14.` than the gap between `14.` and `15.` when this is done. But it is not a problem...

Answer (score 14):

With backslashes you can avoid the list generation altogether, though you *will* now have to leave two whitespaces at the end of each line to force a line break.

```
1\. lol  
2\. pmsl  
4\. rofl  
5\. lmao
```

1. lol
2. pmsl
4. rofl
5. lmao

Comment: Backspaces or Backslashes?  I assume you meant the latter.

Comment: @ClickRick: lol yes